# Как создавать массивы в С++?

Tags: c++, qt

У меня есть переменная она меняется во время работы (это переменная f).
    f =0 ;

После я пытаюсь создать имена для массивов (пример f=3 значит будет создано три массива с названиями "Array1", "Array2", "Array3")

Но я не могу найти встроенную функцию. что бы qt создал массив (CreateFile, CreateArray не сработали )

```
 for (int i = 1; i<f;i++)
{
    QString st = "Array"+ i;
    CreateFile(st,int);
    CreateArray(st, int);
}
```

//--------------------------------------------

Попробывал как тут предложили

```
QMap <QString, QVector<int>> map;
int t_ter = 1;
for (int i = 0; i<f;i++)
{
    QString st = "Array"+ i;
    map[st] =  t_ter;
    t_ter= t_ter+1;
    qDebug() << "map[st]" << map[st];
}
```

но на строку

```
  map[st] =  t_ter;
```

ругается говорит ошибка С2679.
Что я сделал не так ???

Comment: IMHO, в плюсах так не бывает. В Qt можно написать new QVector, например.

Comment: Не буду гадать, с какого языка вы переходите на C++, но тут нет такой **непосредственной** возможности...

Comment: У map[st] значением является тип QVector<int>, поэтому вы не можете указать ему значение типа int

Answer (score 2):

Я так понял, Вам нужно, чтобы просто к массиву можно было получить доступ по какому-то имени?

Просто создайте ассоциативный массив, для этого можно использовать

```
QMap< QString, QVector<int> > map;
```

или

```
std::map< std::string, std::vector<int> > map;
```

Тогда имя будет ключом, по которому всегда можно будет получить доступ к самому массиву, например в Qt:

```
QVector<int> arr( map.Value( "Array1" ) );
```

В зависимости от используемой библиотеки (Qt или std), будут различаться имена функций, но суть одинакова.

Например, добавить массив Вы сможете так (используя Ваши переменные):

```
map[st] = result;
```

Эффективнее, конечно, в этом случае использовать указатели на массивы, так можно будет избежать лишнего копирования, но не хочу сейчас вносить путаницы.

**EDIT:** не могу оставлять комментарии из-за недостаточной репутации, поэтому уточню ответ здесь.

В комментариях Вам ответили, что тип значения должен быть QVector, а не int, поэтому сделайте, например

```
QVector<int> t_ter;
t_ter.Add( 1 );
```

**P.S.** И не играйте с огнём: оставляйте пробел при закрытии вложенных шаблонных параметрах, как это писал я `QMap< QString, QVector<int> >`, а не `QVector<int>>`, потому что некоторые компиляторы могут принять это за потоковый оператор ">>" и потом придётся долго пересобирать все такие места, когда программы станут немного больше.

Comment: `>>` в шаблонах нормально разрешается, начиная с c++11. Т.е. в современном c++ проблем с этим быть не должно.

Answer (score 0):

Из вашего вопроса не совсем понятно, что вам в итоге нужно сделать.

Попытаюсь предположить:

```
// функция возвращает массив массивов int. Длина возвращаемого массива == count
QVector<QVector<int> > makeArrays(int count)
{
    QVector<QVector<int> > result;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        result.push_back(QVector<int>()); // создаём новый массив и добавляем к результату
    }
    return result;
}
```